# Accessing leader node types from compute operations

Tags: amazon-redshift

I've built a view that works perfectly well on it's own.
However, it sources pg_class & pg_namespace, which have leader node only data types.
(in the view, I have extracted the values I need from those data types and cast the values as varchar.)

I now need to create a procedure that calls the view, and returns its data to the caller.
I'm still a bit of a redshift novice, but I believe that the error is because the SProc used compute nodes which don't like my data source being leader-only.

> Warnings:
>
> Column "b.relacl" has unsupported type "aclitem[]". Column "b.nspacl"
> has unsupported type "aclitem[]".
>
> An error occurred when executing the SQL command: CALL
> myschema.permissions_sp('info_results')
>
> ERROR: list_nth_cell: invalid index into list   Where: SQL statement
> "create temp table info_results as select .....

Looking for guidance as to how to get this data out to my end users !!

For background, I am executing via Procedure because pg_class & pg_namespace  would naturally only show result rows based on the caller's identity, and procedures allow me to use "SECURITY DEFINER" and return all rows.

Thanks

**Procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myschema.permissions_sp(INOUT tmp_name character varying(256))
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'drop table if exists ' || tmp_name;
  EXECUTE 'create temp table ' || tmp_name || ' as select schema_name,schema_owner,grantee_type,grantee,p_usage,p_create,object_name,perms,p_select,p_update,p_insert,p_delete,p_truncate,p_references,p_trigger,p_rule from myschema.homebrew_stv';
  EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT on table ' || tmp_name || ' TO myuser';
END;
$$
/
```

**View:**

```
create or replace view myschema.homebrew_stv
as

select 
  case when (s.schema_name in ('information_schema','pg_catalog','pg_toast','pg_internal')) or (s.schema_name like 'pg_temp_%')  then 1 end as issys,
  cast(s.schema_name as varchar(256)) schema_name,
  cast(s.schema_owner as varchar(256)) schema_owner,
  s.grantee_type,
  cast(s.grantee as varchar(256)) grantee,
  s.p_usage,
  s.p_create,
  cast(t."object" as varchar(256)) "object_name",
  cast(t.perms as varchar(256)),
  t.p_select,
  t.p_update,
  t.p_insert,
  t.p_delete,
  t.p_truncate,
  t.p_references,
  t.p_trigger,
  t.p_rule
from 
  myschema.homebrew_schema_xtended s
  left outer join 
  myschema.homebrew_tv_xtended t
  on 
    s.schema_name = t.schema_name and 
    s.grantee_type = t.grantee_type and 
    s.grantee = t.grantee
 where s.grantee <> 'rdsdb'
```

**information_schema.columns**

> table_schema  table_name  column_name data_type
>
> myschema  homebrew_stv    p_rule  integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    p_trigger   integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    p_references    integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    p_truncate  integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    p_delete    integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    p_insert    integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    p_update    integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    p_select    integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    p_create    integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    p_usage integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    issys   integer
> myschema  homebrew_stv    perms   character varying
> myschema  homebrew_stv    object_name character varying
> myschema  homebrew_stv    grantee character varying
> myschema  homebrew_stv    grantee_type    character varying
> myschema  homebrew_stv    schema_owner    character varying
> myschema  homebrew_stv    schema_name character varying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution in the end ... just use a cursor instead of a temp table.

```
BEGIN
  OPEN rs_out FOR select schema_name,schema_owner,grantee_type,grantee,p_usage,p_create,object_name,perms,p_select,p_update,p_insert,p_delete,p_truncate,p_references,p_trigger,p_rule from myschema.homebrew_stv;
END;
```